# 500 OOPS returned for anonymous ftp - vsftpd on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

I just setup up a vsftpd ftp server on 20.04 with anonymous login for download only/not allowing user to change root dir. When trying to `ftp server-ip`, received an error:

```
500 OOPS: vsftpd: cannot locate user specified in 'ftp_username':ftp
Connection closed by remote host.
```

Since this is anonymous ftp server, I am not sure where this `ftp_username` coming from. Here is the `/etc/vsftpd.conf`:

```
listen=NO
listen_ipv6=YES
# Allow anonymous FTP? (Disabled by default).
anonymous_enable=YES
anon_root=/srv/ftp/
no_anon_password=YES
hide_ids=YES
local_enable=NO
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=ftp
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
ssl_enable=NO
```

What is missing with the conf above?

Comment: Is there a user named `ftp` on the system? Check with `getent passwd ftp` for example

Comment: Used to have user ftp and later deleted it. configured for anonymous ftp

Comment: Well, according to `man vsftpd.conf`, `ftp_username` is *"the name of the user we use for handling anonymous FTP"* and its default value is `ftp` - if you have deleted the `ftp` user then you will need to provide another account to use via the `ftp_username` parameter